# Sharing a method in an outside class between two classes, one that implements the other

Tags: c#

**I have looked at the listed questions that seem related and they are a bit different**

I have two DTOs. They already existed in the system and are pretty ingrained and would be pretty hard to change. Therefore, I cannot make widespread changes in the code.

```
 public class DriverScheduleDto
 {
   public string FullName { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
   public string DriverStatus { get; set; }
 }

 public class DriverScheduleAtmDto: DriverScheduleDto
 {
   public string LicenseType { get; set; }
    public string LicenseNumber { get; set; }
    public string MedicalExpirationDate { get; set; }
 }
```

There are methods in a class that use either the DriverScheduleDto class or the DriverScheduleAtmDto class. In this example lets say the code needs to check in each of them if the person is still active based off of the IsDriverActive bool but it needs to be checked in each of the methods that use the Info and DriverScheduleAtmDto classes.

```
private bool IsDriverActive(DriverScheduleDto dto, List<List<DriverScheduleDto>> results)
{
    var group = results.SelectMany(item => item).Where(x => x.FullName == dto.FullName);

    var mostRecent = group.OrderBy(g => g.CreatedDate).Last();

    if (mostRecent.DriverStatus == "Active" || mostRecent.DriverStatus == "Probation")
        return true;

    return false;
}


private bool IsDriverActive(DriverScheduleAtmDto dto, List<List<DriverScheduleAtmDto>> results)
{
    var group = results.SelectMany(item => item).Where(x => x.FullName == dto.FullName);

    var mostRecent = group.OrderBy(g => g.CreatedDate).Last();

    if (mostRecent.DriverStatus == "Active" || mostRecent.DriverStatus == "Probation")
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

The above methods need to be pared down to one method and shared among both Info and MoreInfo.

I have tried creating an interface and associating it with the Info object but that didn't work and wanted a lot of changes within the file and the surrounding code as well. I have also tried a higher level base

Comment: Why not just remove `bool IsPersonAlive(MoreInfo personInfo)`? Both types are `Info`, so the first will work for either

Comment: I cannot remove it. It is necessary for certain printing functionality.  Not to mention that in reality the Info and MoreInfo is a list that needs to be looped through and examined to make sure that values in that entire list are valid before the overall printing. That is why it wont work in an interface. Also, if the functionality is just duplicated in each of the methods that use the DTOs it will not pass review.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by "pared down and shared", if not "refactor all this duplicate code"

Comment: Sorry, I mean that it just needs to be one method, not two and shared between the two types.

Comment: I could check to see if my team lead would approve of something like adding the few properties to the Info class and do it that way. I dont think the higher ups would accept that though.

Comment: But `bool IsPersonAlive(Info personInfo)` already satisfies both `Info` and `MoreInfo` instances as arguments - since both are `Info`. So what's the problem with just removing `bool IsPersonAlive(MoreInfo personInfo)` from the codebase?

Comment: Let me change up my example...

Comment: I don't understand why you can't remove the second overload. But... you also could call the first method from the second: `private bool IsPersonAlive(MoreInfo personInfo) => IsPersonAlive((Info)personInfo);`

Comment: I updated the example so that it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks clumsy, but...

```cs
private bool IsDriverActive<T>(T dto, List<List<T>> results)
    where T : DriverScheduleDto
{
    // implement checking here
}
```

Do you want something like this?

Comment: This did exactly what I needed! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change data type of parameters to dynamic as shown below:

```
    private bool IsDriverActive(dynamic dto, List<List<dynamic>> results)
    {
        var group = results.SelectMany(item => item).Where(x => x.FullName == dto.FullName);

        var mostRecent = group.OrderBy(g => g.CreatedDate).Last();

        if (mostRecent.DriverStatus == "Active" || mostRecent.DriverStatus == "Probation")
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```

Here is the [working code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WoQPur) to illustrate how this works

If you still need to check the type then use "is" to check type as shown below:

```
    private bool IsDriverActive(dynamic dto, List<List<dynamic>> results)
    {
        if (dto is DriverScheduleDto)
        {
            //then do this
        }
        else
        {
            //do that
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this did not work. The code didn't even build.

Comment: Then something else might be wrong in your code. Here is the working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WoQPur